# NSTimer calling method repeatedly after making it nill and invalidate

Tags: ios, api, nstimer

I have used nstimer for creating countdown timer for 60 sec. and at every sec i am calling a method for updating the text of the button. This thing is working good. but once i leave the viewcontroller and go to other view and come back to same view the method is called continuous everytime and changing of the button text also do not work at this nor it calls the api call in it. It is something like it is calling every method and everything but it doesn't change in the view controller

```
self.countDown = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.countDown forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) say:

- invalidate
  **Special Considerations**
  You must send this message from the thread on which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.
  Maybe this is the problem?

EDIT:

Instead of adding the timer to the `currentRunLoop`, you could add it to the run loop of the main thread using `[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]` instead of `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]`, i.e.

```
self.countDown = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.countDown forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

To invalidate it from the main thread, you could use

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
   [self.countDown invalidate];
}];
```

Comment: Here is the code :
 kindly check this

`self.countDown = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.countDown forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];`

Comment: You are adding the timer to the "currentRunLoop". You have to invalidate it also from the same run loop. If you do it from a different thread, the "currentRunLoop" is a different one. So, please, check, that both run loops are the same.

Comment: i do not know how to check the thread on which all the things run

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to manually add the timer to the NSRunLoop? That's typically not necessary. Use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` instead of `timerWithTimeInterval`, to create the timer like so:

```
self.countDown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

That will start the timer, without manually adding it to the NSRunLoop. Then you should be able to stop it with just:

```
[self.countDown invalidate];
```

Comment: but changing the view two time updateCountdown method is called and time is decreased twice.

Comment: Are you certain you're calling `invalidate` when you leave? I would put a breakpoint on the invalidate call to make sure its being hit. I would also check if self.countDown is nil or not when returning to the view. Otherwise, you're going to need to add more code into your question above so we can see what's going on when you setup the timer, when you switch views, and when you come back.

Comment: i am checking but my viewwilldisappear and diddisappear is being not called so how invalidate them ?

Comment: How do you switch views? Where ever you do that, add the `invalidate` call there.

Comment: I think i have issue with MFCSidepanel control it is just pushing every view on the top not popping any view outside.